# Remove duplicate occurence of a specific value from a column and keep unique value of some values

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I got this data `structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2, 2), state = c("Ist hosp adm", "Ist hops disc", "2nd hosp adm",  "2nd hosp disc", "Death", "Ist hosp adm", "Ist hosp disc", "2nd hosp adm",  "2nd hosp disc", "3rd hosp adm", "3rd hosp disc", "3+ hosp adm",  "3+ hosp disc", "3+ hosp adm", "3+ hosp disc", "Death")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -16L))`

And I want to get this. Basically, there are some values which are occuring more than once, of which I want to keep one value and some values which are occuring more than once which i want to remove.
I want a single copy of the 3+ hosp adm and want to remove all the 3+ hosp disc. I hope this makes sense.

```
`structure(list(id2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
state2 = c("Ist hosp adm", "Ist hops disc", "2nd hosp adm", 
"2nd hosp disc", "Death", "Ist hosp adm", "Ist hosp disc", 
"2nd hosp adm", "2nd hosp disc", "3rd hosp adm", "3rd hosp disc", 
"3+ hosp adm", "Death")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))`
```

Comment: Is the expected output correct

Answer (score 0):

We can use `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df1)
```

Comment: distinct(), will remove only the duplicates. But I want to keep distinct values of the 3+ hosp adm, which distinct will achieve. However, I want to remove all the 3+ hosp disc as well. Which distinct keep a single copy of it.

Comment: But in your expected output, I see the `3+` row

Comment: Yes, I got the 3+ hosp adm which I want a single copy of it but i dont want the 3+ hosp disc.

Comment: @kamrankhan can you update your post.  The description in your post is not specific

Comment: Its ok, I got it another way , by filtering my data where the hospital admission were < 5 and it worked. so 3+ hosp adm in my example data mean 4th or more than 4 hopital admission. I wanted to keep only upto 4 admissions. so <5 admission worked. thanks